# Скроллинг по горизонтали мышкой

Tags: jquery

Как сделал я:

```js
//Скрол мышкой
window.onload = function() {
  var scr = $(".scroll");
  scr.mousedown(function() {
    var startX = this.scrollLeft + event.pageX;
    var startY = this.scrollTop + event.pageY;
    scr.mousemove(function() {
      this.scrollLeft = startX - event.pageX;
      this.scrollTop = startY - event.pageY;
      return false;
    });
  });
  $(window).mouseup(function() {
    scr.off("mousemove");
  });
};
//Скрол мышкой
$(function() {
  $('.block').draggable({
    revert: true,
    zIndex: 100,
    revertDuration: 0,
    helper: "clone"
  });
});
```

```css
.scroll {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 300px;
  cursor: all-scroll;
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100px;
}

.sortable.hover {
  background: #cac3c3;
}

.sortable {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 25px 5px 5px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100%
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="scroll">

  <div class="sortable" data-block="1">
    <div class="block">
      Блок1
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок2
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sortable" data-block="2">
    <div class="block">
      Блок11
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок12
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок13
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sortable" data-block="3">
    <div class="block">
      Блок11
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок12
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      Блок13
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

В чем проблема: у меня еще стоит `draggable` и когда используется скрипт скролла, он не дает работать `draggable`

То есть они не хотят работать вмести, либо скролл либо драг

Как сделать, чтобы они работали вмести, может есть другой скрипт скролла мышкой

Если я правильно понимаю, то `scr.mousedown` перехватывает все движения мышки, можно как-то оградить `block` от `mousedown` и `mouseup`?